# How to know which Chrome tab is causing http traffic?

Tags: google-chrome

I have Fiddler (http network sniffer) running and it lists Chrome:xxxx as the source for network traffic and I see every second some http traffic. xxxx is the Windows process id. I thought I would be able to map the process id to the tab's process id but it's the main Browser process so Fiddler is showing the same process id regardless which tab is causing the traffic. The Network tab in dev tools doesn't show anything unless I manually cause the traffic.

What's the way to know which tab is making these background calls?

Comment: Have you tried chrome://net-internals/#http2?

Answer (score 4):

I followed @motivated's advice & chrome://net-internals/#http2 gave me a message saying:

> The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed. Please use [chrome://net-export](http://chrome://net-export) to save netlogs and the external [catapult netlog_viewer](https://chromium.googlesource.com/catapult/+/master/netlog_viewer/) to view them.

The chrome://net-export/ tool lets you export logs to a `.json` file on your machine.

[image: Chrome's net-export tool]

This can be uploaded to the hosted version of [netlog-viewer](https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import), or you can run it locally (if you have anything sensitive, please do the latter).

After uploading, you can go to the `Events` view to see a list of HTTP events & click on one for more detail.

I used this to get to the bottom of something puzzling me: I use LittleSnitch to monitor outgoing network activity & I could see something was regularly using Chrome to upload a bunch of data to [m.stripe.com](https://m.stripe.com). But I've got a zillion tabs open & I don't want to inspect each one, so how do I find the culprit? Using this, I selected one of the upload packets and...

```
1171968: URL_REQUEST
https://m.stripe.com/4
Start Time: 2020-03-04 22:32:29.957

t= 78085 [st=    0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=97296+]
                     --> has_upload = true
                     --> is_pending = true
                     --> load_flags = 0 (NORMAL)
                     --> load_state = 13 (SENDING_REQUEST)
                     --> method = "POST"
                     --> net_error = -1 (ERR_IO_PENDING)
                     --> network_isolation_key = "https://toggl.com https://stripe.network"
```

It was [toggl.com](https://toggl.com)! It'd managed to do ~30 MB in 30 min.

[image: Toggl uploaded 30 MB in 30 min to stripe.com]

So then I blocked it using Privacy Badger :-)

[image: Using Privacy Badger to block stripe.com trackers]

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on Chrome's title bar (not on a tab), and select **Task Manager**. It will show mem usage, cpu usage, and pid, per tab.

*Stats for nerds* may be of help to you as well. This is a button/link on the bottom left of the task manager which displays more advanced and detailed information.

Comment: Please provide as much detail in your answer as possible. What is "stats for nerds" ? How is it accessed?

Comment: edited to elaborate

Comment: Please explain how Stats For nerds shows which tab shows the specific http calls I am seeing. I am not interested about the other stats.

Comment: I found it here: Window -> Task Manager

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Shift+ESC = Chrome or Opera Task-Manager shows Network traffic.
For me it the guilty was Translator addon
https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/translator/
Now silence :)